# How to make a copy of the Android Sensor SensorEvent Object

Tags: android, android-sensors, sensormanager

I have a sparesArray which I use to store & batch SensorEvents by holding onto each sensor typeId and SensorEvent object until a timer fires.

```
  SparseArray<SensorEvent> sensorEventMap   = new SparseArray<SensorEvent>();

  public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    synchronized (this) {
        sensorEventMap.put(event.sensor.getType(), event);
    }
}
```

I am having issues where the SensorEvent is getting overwritten in the array before my timer fires, so I'd like to make a copy of the SensorEvent and store the copy in the array instead.

How can I make a copy of SensorEvent ?

I need the whole SensorEvent, not just the data values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible as it is a system class you wont be able to make it implement the cloneable interface.  Better to just create your own clone class and copy it yourself.